# Running multiple query (increase a value) at a same time in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have column in my mysql database named "number" and its value is 50.the following code are in a php file.I want to know if 20 users exactly run this code at a same time,what will be the value of number? 51 or 70 or ... ?

```
$conn->autocommit(FALSE);
$SQL1 = $conn->query("UPDATE table1 SET number = number + 1 WHERE id = '$TheUserid'");
$SQL2 = $conn->query("INSERT INTO ..."); // INSERT some data to another table
if ($SQL1 && $SQL2)
{
    ($conn->commit())
}
else
{
    $conn->rollback();
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be 70.
DML queries are atomic in Mysql database and creates its own exclusive lock.